# PHP set current time unchanged

Tags: php, date, timezone

I want to set the current timezone by using `set_default_timezone('')` but the problem is that, when I modify the time in my laptop like adding hours or minutes, it also change in my returned value `date('H:i:s')`.
Any ideas ? How to prevent that and keep the time returned by `date()` function independent of the time changes?

Comment: are you working in localhost?

Comment: if you are working in local, then the server time and your machine time will be the same. Because both are located in the same machine.

Comment: indeed yes! my application runs in local server and i need to prevent users to change the time, how could i proceed then?

Comment: you can only prevent this by setting user account previlages(prevent changing time).

Comment: Your question is unclear as asked.  Please edit your question, providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks.